# How can I set a size limit for an "int" datatype in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I am experimenting with PostgreSQL coming from SQL using MySQL and I simply wish to create a table with this piece of code which is valid SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE flat_10
(
  pk_flat_id INT(30) DEFAULT 1,
  rooms      INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  room_label CHAR(1) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (flat_id)
);
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:    syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:   pk_flat_id integer(30) DEFAULT 1,
```

I have conducted searches on the web and found no answer and I cant seem to find an answer in the PostgreSQL manual. What am I doing wrong?

I explicitly want to set a limit to the number of digits that can be inserted into the "pk_flat_id" field

Comment: Your code is valid SQL only in MySQL :-)

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createdomain.html if this type needs to be reusable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I explicitly want to set a limit to the number of digits that can be inserted into the "pk_flat_id" field*

Your current table definition does ***not*** impose a "size limit" in any way. In MySQL the parameter for the `int`data type is only a *hint* for applications on the display width of the column when *displaying* it.

You can store the value 2147483647 in an `int(1)` without any problems.

If you want to limit the values to be stored in an integer column you can use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE flat_10
(
  pk_flat_id bigint DEFAULT 1,
  rooms      integer NOT NULL,
  room_label CHAR(1) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (flat_id), 
  constraint valid_number 
      check (pk_flat_id <= 999999999)
);
```

Comment: Why did you specify a size (Or whatever the CHAR(n) stands for )for the CHAR datatype on the room_label column?

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe: because you did that in your original table as well. And for character data types, the size **does** specify a limit.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that you use `numeric` or `decimal` types.  These are documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).

Note that these types can take an optional precision argument, but you don't want that.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE flat_10
(
  pk_flat_id DECIMAL(30) DEFAULT 1,
  rooms      DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
  room_label CHAR(1) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (pk_flat_id)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0f97a) is a SQL Fiddle.

I don't think that Postgres supports unsigned decimals.  And, it seems like you really want serial types for your keys and the long number of digits is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Changing integer to numeric works.

```
CREATE TABLE flat_10
(
  pk_flat_id bigint DEFAULT 1,
  rooms      numeric NOT NULL,
  room_label CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
);
```