# Postgres: How can I fix this create query?

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, createquery

I am learning Postgres and trying a create command. But it is giving error which I am unable to understand which is making error.
The command is :

```
CREATE TABLE Package (
    id smallint NOT NULL primary key,
    package_name varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    count integer(2) default null,
    pkg_desc varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    bucket_name varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    active bit(1),
    status INT(2) default null,
    metadata JSONB,
    path varchar ( 45 ) default null,
    created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    run_status INT(5) 
)
```

And the error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 186
```

Comment: you should paste the query  that landed at this error.

Comment: you cannot specify size for integer or int data types. just remove that and you should be good.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Package ( 
id smallint NOT NULL primary key, 
package_name varchar ( 45 ) not null, 
updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
count integer(2) default null, 
pkg_desc varchar ( 45 ) not null, 
bucket_name varchar ( 45 ) not null, 
active bit(1), status INT(2) default null, 
metadata JSONB, path varchar ( 45 ) default null, 
created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
run_status INT(5) )

Comment: Also - you use integer and int - any reasons?

Comment: There is nothing like INT(2) in Postgresql.  Integer (or int) is legal but other numeric type might suit you.  You can find the available types here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype.html

Comment: The reason I used both is I was just trying ...the use case is it should be a interger with specific limit.

Comment: @AdilKhalil what if there is a limit like int(5) ,which datatype has to be used?

Comment: What do you expect from an INT(5) ? What numbers should it support? When you have that answer, you can pick the right PostgreSQL datatype

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a size limit for an "int" datatype in PostgreSQL 9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883306/how-can-i-set-a-size-limit-for-an-int-datatype-in-postgresql-9-5)

Answer (score 1):

You use `integer(2)` and INT`(2)` to create a column. You must not add the number. Integers are fixed size. Also you should decide on one way to write it
Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Package (
    id smallint NOT NULL primary key,
    package_name varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    count INT default null,
    pkg_desc varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    bucket_name varchar ( 45 ) not null,
    active bit(1),
    status INT default null,
    metadata JSONB,
    path varchar ( 45 ) default null,
    created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    run_status INT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`integer` and `int` types don't accept arguments.
You can't write it like `integer(2)`, which gives syntax error.

```
create table Package (
  id smallint not null primary key
  , package_name varchar(45) not null
  , updated_at timestamp null default current_timestamp
  , count integer default null
  , pkg_desc varchar(45) not null
  , bucket_name varchar(45) not null
  , active bit(1)
  , status int default null
  , metadata jsonb
  , path varchar(45) default null
  , created_at timestamp null default current_timestamp
  , run_status int
)
```

The official document should be helpful:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype.html